# Translate latin phrase

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I remember once reading a phrase like "Nam Iesus Christus mori fiat/fiet (not quite sure which)" or something like that. I don't remember any more if it is the precise phrase and I'm not sure where I saw it. But if it is such, what would this phrase mean? My Latin is still pretty horrible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"For Jesus Christ will be made to die" would be the translation with 'fiet.' It's probably fiet, because using fiat would make that outcome less certain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is a strange phrase so I probably am remembering it completely wrong. Even so I thank you very much for clearing it up for me!